# requestAnimationFrame vs EventListener, concurrent or consecutive

Tags: javascript, event-listener, requestanimationframe

I have a `requestAnimationFrame` loop and multiple EventListeners (for keyboard/mouse).

Am I guaranteed the functions they call will always run 1 after the other, or is there a chance they will sometimes run concurrently?

```js
function f1() {
  ...
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', f1)

...

function f2() {
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(f2)
}
requestAnimationFrame(f2)
```

Comment: JS is single-threaded. Once an asynchronous function is executed from the event loop, it'll run synchronously to completion. So there's no way to wind up with concurrent execution of pieces of the code between the two functions, like interleaving statements or two statements running simultaneously. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#run-to-completion